# Anchor and object size

Tags: c#, winforms

in the C# form, I fixed my objects left and right with the anchor tool, but when I increase the screen resolution when I run the program, the objects remain small. What I want is for the items I fixed with anchor to grow the same way when I increase the resolution (Example, 1150,780 size | Button1 size 12, 1920,1080 | Button1 enlarged from 12 proportionally to you)

What I expect is for my objects and the window to grow evenly as they grow.

Comment: We don't know what your design looks like.  Do you have the control inside a panel?

Comment: Is your app dpi-aware? Do you design while your display scale is 100%? What is the value of the `Form.AutoScaleMode` property? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/14171304) and the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: My friend who added it to the code added an external sizing code and because of this, our setting in the properties tab did not work, we fixed it, thank you.